# SQL no funciona, where

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT id, date_start, date_end as "ID" 
FROM project_task a
inner join project_task_type b
where a.date_start is not NULL and a.date_end is NULL
```

Da error en where

Comment: Por favor, se más explicito en el error indicando el error que te da

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indica @Fly, has de añadir la condición al INNER JOIN

```
SELECT id, date_start, date_end as "ID" 
FROM project_task a
inner join project_task_type b ON b.id=a.id_task_type
where a.date_start is not NULL and a.date_end is NULL
```

La parte de **ON b.id=a.id_task_type** es la clave que falta a tu query

Answer (score 4):

El error está en que no tienes cláusula `ON` en el `JOIN`

Debería ser algo como:

```
SELECT id, date_start, date_end as "ID" 
FROM project_task a
inner join project_task_type b ON b.id=a.id_task_type
where a.date_start is not NULL and a.date_end is NULL
```

Puedes revisar la sintaxis del `JOIN` en la documentación oficial: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html